# onClick input text readonly form use inline

Tags: html, events, dom

I have problem with onclick input form is readonly but use it inline. 
I can do only onclick is disable Example:

```
<input type="text" onClick=this.disabled=true />
```

this one is work but what I need is when onClick event is readonly I try this :

```
<input type="text" onClick=this.readonly=true />
```

but it  still not work.

Comment: Please double quote your attribute value `onClick`

Comment: There is no meaning of making it `readonly`, when you do `onclick` on a textbox.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

This has been answered

`onclick="document.getElementById('Tbox').readOnly=true"`

http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?146525-Toggle-READONLY

Answer (score 1):

`<input type="text" onClick="this.readOnly=true" />`

Answer (score 1):

There is a little difference between [**`HTML <input> readonly Attribute`**](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp) and [**`Text readOnly Property`**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_readonly.asp).

> **readOnly:** The readOnly property sets or returns whether a text field is read-only, or not.

change `readonly` to `readOnly`, it will work correctly.

```
<input type="text" onClick='this.readOnly = true;' value='checkMe'/>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wWPsy/)